# What programming language do I use, when I write code in terminal of Linux?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I was advised to use this code to implement watch in Linux:

```
while true; do echo -ne "`date`\r"; done
```

Now I wonder what programming language is it written in, and additionally can you advice how to learn this programming language?

Comment: A number of languages can be used, but you're probably looking for Python.

Answer (score 2):

The above code is written in Shell Script. There are many shell/terminals avaialble in linux (BASH, ZSH, SH etc). Bash is very popular and widely used. Bash is the default shell for many linux OS like Ubuntu.

There are many sites provides good tutorials for Bash/shell scripting. One of my favourite is https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/